# Why does the xlc switch -qhaltonmsg not work?

Tags: compiler-warnings, aix, xlc

I am usng AIX `xlc` and attempting to use the [`-qhaltonmsg=...`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-c-and-cpp-aix/13.1.3?topic=descriptions-qhaltonmsg) switch to make certain detected messages fatal. It's not working and I can't figure out why. Here is a sample program:

```
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Here is an invocation that does not go as expected:

```
> xlc test.c -c -qinfo=pro -qhaltonmsg=1506-304; echo $?
"test.c", line 3.9: 1506-304 (I) No function prototype given for "foo".
0
```

The `-qinfo=pro` switch enables the "No function prototype" message, that much works. The `-qhaltonmsg=1506-304` switch is supposed to elevate the given message to (S) severe, and stop compilation with a nonzero exit code. That does not appear to happen. Why not?

I am using AIX 7.1, if that matters.

Comment: Install gcc, it has `-Werror` option.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: I'm working on a big legacy system that does not build with gcc.

Comment: Well that is a problem that worth fixing. For example, if you make your program gcc-compatible, you will be able to run in on Linux with valgrind: it will find tons of problems you were not aware.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: Yes absolutely, porting to Linux so we can use modern tools is one eventual goal. A rough guess is 3 million lines of code written starting around 1992 and maintained continuously since then. Many things are tied specifically to AIX too, which will require rework. It's a big job, I'm starting with the small stuff.

Comment: I actually got return code 1 with the same code and command. What's your XL compiler version? (`-qversion`)

Comment: @QiuChaofan: I have `IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V11.1 (5724-X13) Version: 11.01.0000.0007`

Comment: I tried with XL C/C++ 16, not sure the behavior you met is expected to XL C/C++ 11.

Comment: @QiuChaofan: Thanks, at least I now know that the behaviour has changed (hopefully for the better!) in later versions of XLC.